# Run statement in terminal if user enters a certain key otherwise continue with raw_input in python

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to be able to have the terminal ask questions to the user but I also want the user to be able to enter an alternate character which would be able to print something out and I was wondering how to do this throughout several user inputs. Thanks this is a chunk of my code.

```
user_choice = []
if user_choice == "b":
    print "we have: strawberry, chocolate, vanilla, and mint."

else:
    # run the code like normal 

user_choice.append( raw_input("would you like some ice cream?: "))
if user_choice[-1] =="yes":
    print "Here you go."
user_choice.append( raw_input("would you like some cake?: "))
if user_choice[-1] =="yes":
    print "Ooh it looks like we just ran out of cake."
```

Comment: Why not use raw_input to read the key selection? It doesn't need to be shoved into the `user_choice` list.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would make a function that computes your responses based on the current question and the user input. You can also have a separate function which handles the convoluted process of asking questions so you don't need to repeat your code much. It makes it easy to extend your code this way.

```
import sys

def getResponse(question, userInput):
    # User giving input that doesn't answer the question, but still 
    # invokes an appropriate response
    if userInput == 'b': 
        return ("We have: strawberry, chocolate, vanilla, and mint.", False)
    # Finally, if the user gives input that answers your question
    # default case for unhandled input is included
    else:
        return {
            ("would you like some ice cream?: ", "yes") : 
                ("Here you go.", True),
            ("would you like some cake?: ", "yes") :
                ("Ooh it looks like we just ran out of cake.", True)
        }.setdefault((question, userInput), ("", False))

def askQuestion(question):
    sys.stdout.write(question)
    answered = False
    while not answered:
        response, answered = getResponse(question, raw_input())
        if response: print response

# Ask questions
askQuestion("would you like some ice cream?: ")
askQuestion("would you like some cake?: ")
```

The functionality you ask for can be easily handled through the use of flow control based on conditionals. Notice how I only used an if statement and a while loop to find the solution. I also used an anonymous dictionary, but this is not necessary, another if statement could have easily done the trick. if statements and while loops are examples of flow control.

You can find more information on flow control in Chapter 3 of the Python tutorial.